# Load a list from a SQL Server database to C# combobox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, datasource

I have a database with 2 categories that I turn into a list and plan to use it as a data source for a drop down combobox in C#

Category B is connected to category B for example (in database):

```
CatA CatB
a     1
a     2
b     3
b     4
```

The plan is to use droplist to choose catA and on change it will load CatB to the 2nd droplist.

So if I choose CATA=a I will get CATB=1,2

The code to get CATA

```
public List<string> getCatAlist()
{
    List<string> catAlist = new List<string>();
    List<string> filteredList = new List<string>();

    _con.Open(); 
    _cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM category";

    var dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
        catAlist.Add(dr["catA"].ToString());

    _con.Close();
    filteredList = catAlist.Distinct().ToList();
    return filteredList;
}
```

The code to get CATB

```
public List<string> getCatBlist(string catA)
{
    List<string> catBlist = new List<string>();

    _con.Open();
    _cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE catA='"+catA+"';";

    var dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
        catBlist.Add(dr["catB"].ToString());

    _con.Close();

    return catBlist;
}
```

The problem is to set the list's as datasource for the combobox

I open a connection to the database and on the first run it loads the list, but when I try to use it again it converts it to a static list for the datasource.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: tip: cmdtxt for CatAlist could be `select distinct CatA from category`. so the cpu doesn't have to do that work. and can you post the `OnSelectionChanged` code, that seems a lot more relevant than the SQL code.

Comment: @RadioSpace right now have problem with that, the visual studio somehow killed the code, more or less onselection change comboB.datasoure=getCatBlist(comboA.text);

Comment: @T.S. the do change but not a lot, i can rethink it to only do once while loading having to reload if i add new. or might add refresh button with command to update global list.

Answer (score 0):

If your categories are not very dynamic you can create Stored Proc where you make 2 calls - this optional, you can make two separate calls to DB

```
Select ... From Cat...
Select ... From Cat...
```

In .Net use

```
cmd.ExecuteReader
```

And use

```
reader.NextResult
```

...to retrieve each set of records.
Create classes for your categories (pseudo-code)

```
class CatA {
    int value
    string display
}

class CatB {
    int parent
    int value
    string display
}
```

Fill your lists

```
List<CatA> listA;
List<CatA> listB;
```

Set your CatA combo properties

```
cboA.valuemember = "value";
cboA.displaymember = "display";
cboA.datasource = listA; // set DS last for better performance
```

Now, you can do this on `listA` `SelectedIndexChanged`

```
// Read comment 
var subListCatB = listB.Where(i => i.parent == ((CatA)listA.SelectedItem).value).ToList() 
//I think you need to use 'where' here but if you have A, which has no B then you need null check

cboB.valuemember = "value";
cboB.displaymember = "display";
cboB.datasource = subListCatB ; // set DS last for better performance
```

This is it